# React App. Fatal Error after npm run build

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have an error when running 'npm run build':

> node scripts/build.js
>
> Creating an optimized production build...
>
> <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> [432:0x38f0d20]   440313 ms: Mark-sweep 1356.4 (1439.3) -> 1356.3
>   (1439.8) MB, 673.6 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure GC in old space
>   requested [432:0x38f0d20]   440848 ms: Mark-sweep 1356.3 (1439.8) ->
>   1356.3 (1420.3) MB, 534.3 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested [432:0x38f0d20]   441238 ms: Mark-sweep 1356.3 (1420.3) ->
>   1356.3 (1420.3) MB, 389.8 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> Security context: 0x112153c25879 
>       0: builtin exit frame: stringify(this=0x112153c090a9 ,0x1863fd022d1 ,0x1863fd022d1
>   ,0x3befa98ff2f1 )
>
> ```
> 1: arguments adaptor frame: 1->3
> 2: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [/var/www/tixxio.loc/node_modules/webpack/lib/SourceMapDevToolPlugin.js:173]
> ```
>
> [bytecode=0x2534cd2bf819 offset=238](this=0x1863fd022d...
>
> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
>   out of memory  1: node::Abort() [node]  2: 0x8c20ec [node]  3:
>   v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [node]  4:
>   v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node] 
>   5: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int,
>   v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]  6:
>   v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten(v8::internal::Handle,
>   v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]  7:
>   v8::internal::JsonStringifier::SerializeString(v8::internal::Handle)
>   [node]  8: v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result
>   v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_(v8::internal::Handle,
>   bool, v8::internal::Handle) [node]  9:
>   v8::internal::JsonStringifier::SerializeArrayLikeSlow(v8::internal::Handle,
>   unsigned int, unsigned int) [node] 10:
>   v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result
>   v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_(v8::internal::Handle,
>   bool, v8::internal::Handle) [node] 11:
>   v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result
>   v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_(v8::internal::Handle,
>   bool, v8::internal::Handle) [node] 12:
>   v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Stringify(v8::internal::Handle,
>   v8::internal::Handle,
>   v8::internal::Handle) [node] 13:
>   v8::internal::Builtin_JsonStringify(int, v8::internal::Object**,
>   v8::internal::Isolate*) [node] 14: 0x33d5b940697d Aborted (core
>   dumped) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 134 npm ERR!
>   tixxio@0.1.0 build: `node scripts/build.js` npm ERR! Exit status 134
>   npm ERR!  npm ERR! Failed at the tixxio@0.1.0 build script. npm ERR!
>   This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional
>   logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/ihor/.npm/_logs/2018-08-20T09_54_34_401Z-debug.log

A complete log of this run:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.3.0
3 info using node@v8.11.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle tixxio@0.1.0~prebuild: tixxio@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle tixxio@0.1.0~build: tixxio@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle tixxio@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle tixxio@0.1.0~build: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/tixxio.loc/node_modules/.bin:/home/ihor/bin:/home/ihor/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/home/ihor/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/ihor/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
9 verbose lifecycle tixxio@0.1.0~build: CWD: /var/www/tixxio.loc
10 silly lifecycle tixxio@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'node scripts/build.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle tixxio@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 134  signal: null
12 info lifecycle tixxio@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: tixxio@0.1.0 build: `node scripts/build.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 134
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:304:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid tixxio@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /var/www/tixxio.loc
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-32-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v8.11.2
19 verbose npm  v6.3.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 134
22 error tixxio@0.1.0 build: `node scripts/build.js`
22 error Exit status 134
23 error Failed at the tixxio@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 134, true ]
```

I've updated all dependencies. How can I solve the error?
Thank you for advice.

Comment: It seems like you have incredibly large bundle. Webpack is running out of memory while assembling a large chunk of your code. You can try to disable source maps by setting GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false in your .env file.